# SQL ON JOIN LIKE (% before last 3 characters)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-like

I am currently using

`Left OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.IDNumber`

so ID and IDNumbers are 12 digits, example `607120670001` and only `0001` changes.

I am interested in matching only first 8 Character/digits. example `60712067%`

data

```
TableA              TableB
607120670001     607120670002         (Match)
507120670001     507120670001         (Match)
123456780001     123456790001         (Not Match)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What data type are those columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use trunc() function to make the 4 last digits equal to 0000.

```
Left OUTER JOIN TableB ON trunc(TableA.ID, -4) = trunc(TableB.IDNumber, -4)
```

Comment: Lifesaver and very simple solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

or, if defined as varchar then

```
Left OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.ID LIKE SUBSTR(TableB.IDNumber,0,8) || '%'
```

Comment: If it's not a varchar it can be turned into one by using `to_char()`